# Apache JMeter showing different result in windows and linux for same test

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have an apache jemeter 5.0 installed,
    i) locally in windows 
   ii) in aws ec2 server.

In local windows for 2000 users it's showing 5% error, screen shot:

[image]

Error screen:
[image]

**But I ran the same test in AWS EC2 for **20,000** (note twenty thousand), but it doesn't show any error (error is 0 percent)**

```
2018-11-27 08:27:51,464 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary +   1730 in 00:00:21 =   80.7/s Avg:  1091 Min:    10 Max: 17343 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 20000 Finished: 20000
2018-11-27 08:27:51,464 INFO o.a.j.r.Summariser: summary =  60000 in 00:06:05 =  164.5/s Avg:   351 Min:    10 Max: 17343 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows has [limit](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html) of thousands concurrent TCP connections

> When a client makes a connect() call to make a connection to a server, then the client invisible/implicit bind the socket to a local dynamic (anonymous, ephemeral, short-lived) port number. The default range for dynamic ports in Windows is 1024 to 5000, thus giving 3977 outbound concurrent connections for each IP Address. It is possible to change the upper limit with this DWORD registry key:
>
> ```
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \System \CurrentControlSet \Services \Tcpip \Parameters]
> MaxUserPort = 5000 (Default = 5000, Max = 65534)
> ```